# Dice rolling problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Alice and Bob are playing a game. Alice has an $a$-sided die. Bob has a $b$-sided die. (The faces of an $n$-sided die have numbers $1$ through $n$ written on them.)
The game is simple: Each player rolls their die, and the player who rolls a strictly larger number wins. (It is possible that neither player wins.)
What is the expected value of the number Alice rolled.

For example if $a = 4$ and $b = 2$ then the result is $3.2$.

Comment: The **unconditional** expectation? Of course $2.5$ if $a=4$. That is presumably not what you are after: the question needs to be modified.

Comment: can you reorient me please ?

Comment: I guess it is *possible* you were asked this very simple question, answer $(a+1)/2$. But you were probably asked a quite a bit harder question, such as the expected value of Alice's number **given** that she won.

Comment: The question is the most probable value that alice has rolled in order to win.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I think you're right, based on "...the result is 3.2", which is the correct answer to the conditional you pose.

Comment: "Most probable" is poor wording for expectation, it sounds like (conditional) mode. They should have said expectation, or mean.

Comment: Any formula for this problem ?

Comment: @user2232305 First get the problem straight (see comments above, double-check with your original assignment)

Comment: This the problem statement. It's a copy paste. I can give more examples: 3
3
Returns: 2.6666666666666665

Comment: @user2232305 : .. returns ? Then give us the code/link whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method, with the small numbers you give, is to **list all possibilities**.

```
  1 2 3 4
1 = A A A
2 B = A A
```

Alice can win in five ways. Her rolls in these five cases are 2, 3, 4, 3, and 4. The mean of these is 3.2, as in your example.

A more complete solution, and maybe a more practical one if the numbers are large, involves **using a formula for conditional expectation.**

- Let $W$, $X$ and $Y$ be our random variables; $W$ is the number Bob rolls, $X$ is the number Alice rolls, and $Y$ is whether Alice wins.
- The conditional expectation formula says that $E\left[X\mid Y=\text{yes}\right] = \sum\limits_{x}\left( x\cdot P\left(X=x\mid Y=\text{yes}\right)\right)$
- The conditional probability can be expanded: $P\left(X=x\mid Y=\text{yes}\right) = \frac{P\left(X=x \cap Y=\text{yes}\right)}{P\left(Y=\text{yes}\right)}$
- Relatedly, we can also say $P\left(Y=\text{yes}\mid X=x\right) = \frac{P\left(X=x \cap Y=\text{yes}\right)}{P\left(X=x\right)}$
- But $P\left(Y=\text{yes}\mid X=x\right) = P\left(W<x\right) = \begin{cases} \frac{x-1}{b} &\text{if } x\le b\\ 1 &\text{if } x>b \end{cases}$ where $b$ is Bob's maximum roll, as per your definition.
- Hence, $P\left(X=x\mid Y=\text{yes}\right) = \frac{P\left(W\le x\right)\cdot P\left(X=x\right)}{P\left(Y=\text{yes}\right)}$
- Meanwhile, for any *possible* roll $x$, $P\left(X=x\right) = \frac{1}{a}$ where $a$ is Alice's maximum roll.
- What is $P\left(Y=\text{yes}\right)$? That's trickier.

  - There are $ab$ possible outcomes.
  - Of those, $d = \text{min}\left(a,b\right)$ are draws, and $\frac{d^2 - d}{2}$ are wins for whoever has the smaller number of rolls possible. The rest are wins for whoever has the greater number of rolls.
  - Thus, $P\left(Y=\text{yes}\right) = \begin{cases} 1 - \frac{a + 1}{2b} &\text{if } a\le b\\ 1 - \frac{b + 1}{2a} &\text{if } a>b \end{cases}$
    (Deriving all of these is left as an exercise for the reader.)
- Putting it all together: $E\left[X\mid Y=\text{yes}\right] = \sum\limits_{x} x\cdot f\left(x\right)$ where $f\left(x\right) = \begin{cases} \frac{x-1}{ab\left(1-\frac{a+1}{2b}\right)} &\text{if } a\le b\\ \frac{x-1}{ab\left(1-\frac{b+1}{2a}\right)} &\text{if } x\le b<a\\ \frac{1}{a\left(1-\frac{b+1}{2a}\right)} &\text{if } b<x\le a \end{cases}$

So it doesn't save you *all* the effort, but now you go over all possible rolls for Alice (all $x \in[1,a]$), rather than all possible rolls for both Alice and Bob.

Feel free to check my working *thoroughly*; I started this yesterday when it was late and I was tired, and it's getting to that point again tonight. ;-)